# Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

I am trying to send a fetch Request with BASE64 Encoded BLOB data.

When validating the JSON through different services, it proves as valid JSON.

```
export function sendRecording1(blob){
let base64data; 
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob); 
reader.onloadend = function() {
  base64data = reader.result;                
  //base64data = base64data.substring(22);

  base64data = base64data.toString();

  let body = JSON.stringify({text: base64data, id: "blob"});
  //console.log(body);
    return fetch(url, {
    method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
    async: true,
    //body: JSON.stringify({ text: base64data, id: "blob" }), 
    body: body,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  }).then(res => res.json())
```

But it seems like fetch() doesnt like that Base 64 Body and gives me the Error: Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0

This also seems to happen when the body is reaching over 100.000bytes.
Which is weird as it was working when I had other files that big.

The Base64 Data are being made from a .WAV file for voice recording.

Comment: It looks like you're not putting quotes around the base 64 string.

Comment: it sounds like your response isn't json

Comment: Inspect the response in your browser and ensure that it's a valid JSON. I agree with Daniel, it doesn't look like it's a valid JSON.

Comment: providing a capture of error stack trace might be useful

Comment: The weird thing is, I really tried it but everythin below 97.000 Bytes works. 

This is the Stack trace:
index.js:2178 Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 0
__stack_frame_overlay_proxy_console__ @ index.js:2178
(anonymous) @ send.js:103
Promise.catch (async)  
reader.onloadend @ send.js:102
FileReader (async)  
sendRecording1 @ send.js:80
(anonymous) @ rtcspeech.js:41
(anonymous)

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue few weeks back not sure exactly what I did. try this and debug it will help.

```
 // .then(res => res.json()) // comment this out for now
  .then(res => res.text())          // convert to plain text
  .then(text => console.log(text))  // then log it out
```

https://daveceddia.com/unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0/

Comment: Unfortunaetly this is already regarding the answer from the server. But the sending process is already messed up.